# Merge dictionaries and add values

Tags: python

I have several dictionaries which I'd like to combine such that if a key is in multiple dictionaries the values are added together. For example:

```
d1 = {1: 10, 2: 20, 3: 30}
d2 = {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3}
d3 = {0: 0}

merged = {1: 11, 2: 22, 3: 33, 0: 0}
```

What is the best way to do this in Python? I was looking at defaultdict and trying to come up with something. I'm using Python 2.6.

Comment: None of these are really duplicates.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I think both of those are different -- the first one doesn't do the Counter-like arithmetic, and the second one doesn't seem to mind the loss of the keys with zero values.  (Which actually surprises me -- up until today I'd never known that `Counter` objects dropped the zero-valued keys when doing arithmetic.)

Comment: [Here's](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/collections.py#l598) the relevant line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using a `defaultdict`:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for di in [d1,d2,d3]:
...   for k,v in di.items():
...     d[k] += v
...
>>> dict(d)
{0: 0, 1: 11, 2: 22, 3: 33}
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

With the very most python standard functions and libraries:

```
dlst = [d1, d2, d3]
for i in dlst:
    for x,y in i.items():
        n[x] = n.get(x, 0)+y
```

Instead of using `if-else` checks, using `dict.get` with default value `0` is simple and easy.

Comment: That *might* be a bit faster that `defaultdict` usage, but iw would be so small and quite ignorable.

Answer (score 2):

without importing anything. .

```
d4={}
for d in [d1,d2,d3]:
    for k,v in d.items():
        d4.setdefault(k,0)
        d4[k]+=v
print d4
```

output:

```
{0: 0, 1: 11, 2: 22, 3: 33}
```

Comment: Also `Counter` *already* implements `__add__` the way the OP wants.

Comment: I can see the reason for this was to allow the `0:0` to exist, however since OP has python 2.6 it won't work

Comment: i have removed `Counter` and see the updated answer. .without importing anything. .